# A solution of P=NP breaks quantum ciphers

Tags: physics, mathematics

Somebody finds an effective NP-complete algorithm.

Then he breaks quantum ciphers by reversing time (time can be made backward by quantum symmetries, so the difference between forward and backward is that in backward direction the laws of physics are a cipher) and acting backward in time bringing quantum states to a state desirable for him.

Viable or no?

Comment: Welcome Porton. I'm concerned that uncertainty (indeterminacy) works the same in both directions, so you'd be working with probability functions rather than ciphers.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane A physicist in Internet convinced me (it's a too long lecture to repeat now) that we live in weakly interacting many-worlds quantum mechanics. The only ultimate reality of our universe is wave function, measurements are just approximations of the wave function. Apparently, in backward direction there is no uncertainty, because worlds merge rather than split.

Comment: I'd love a link to that if it's available. Maybe someone did construct a convincing argument, I'm sure you could swing it for a story.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane This Russian-language video, apparently: https://youtu.be/fFHBLwuKI-E - I asked the author which article he refers to and it is on arXiv ... (I lost it). It is about "quantum decoherence." and is quite complex to read.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I'll see if there's a transcript as my Russian extends to ordering a beer and little else.

Comment: If your world follows this theory of weakly interacting many-world quantum mumbo jumbo, than probably, if it doesn't maybe not? Ultimately it's up to you as worldbuilder to decide what rules your world follows. We can't tell you what rules to choose to abide by.

Comment: I believe in many-worlds (weakly interacting).

Comment: It doesn't matter what you believe. It matters what you choose for your world. For instance as an atheist (who strongly believes there are no gods) I can still create worlds with gods in them. We can't build your world for you or tell you whether some technobabble will or will not solve NP problems in polynomial time.

Comment: Ask yourself is easy to find and easy to check the same thing, up til now nobody can answer so again what is time vandalism got to do with it?

Comment: This question needs some meat on its bones.  What's a "quantum cipher"?  Secure quantum codes rely on a single quantum state being measured at two distant locations.  The sort of prime number ciphers used by PGP etc aren't quantum, but can be broken with the P=NP algorithm.  And what does any of it have to do with the past?  There might be a decent idea here but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is gobbledygook. It reads like a bunch of sci-fi buzzwords and I cannot tell what you have in your head.

Comment: @MikeSerfas I meant "quantum code".

Answer (score 1):

The usefulness of quantum communication is in [key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange), but also in the way that it makes any attempt to eavesdrop on a communication channel obvious, because the eavesdropped will collapse the quantum states being transmitted. It doesn't matter if the observer can interpret the contents of the channel (and P=NP won't help them there) because their interference cannot be hidden. <sub>note though that this can constitute a denial of service making it impossible to send information across the channel, but that's not the same as knowing what is being sent</sub>

P=NP would render the key-exchange process pointless for all currently known symmetric ciphers (because [3SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) is NP-complete) and probably all our current asymmetric ciphers too (though it isn't clear at this point if eg. the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) is in NP), but one can still use a quantum communication channel to securely distribute a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), safe in the knowledge that it cannot have been observed by a third party without your noticing (and if it was observed, throw it away and start again). P=NP doesn't crack one-time pads, so secure communication is still possible.

All that remains is to find a suitable encryption algorithm in a [higher complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class). We don't have one yet, but I suspect it is only a matter of time.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand me: I propose breaking quantum ciphers _by acting backward in time_ using a solution of P=NP.

Comment: @porton yes, which sounds like garbage to me. It doesn't matter whether you're right or not though, because by interfering with a quantum communications channel your actions will be revealed to the communicating parties, who will repeat key exchange until interference goes away, possibly using some other communication channel. All you can do is a denial of service attack, and you can do that without magical handwavium.

Comment: But I propose to break a quantum cipher _before_ they even start to hide.